# Server + GUI installed, starting to get messy

Tags: 10.10, unity, server

I installed Ubuntu server and then I wanted a GUI and I didn't want the server anymore.  So I installed the GUI and every-time I restart my computer it goes to an Ubuntu loading screen which "loads" forever.  I switch over to a virtual terminal and I execute startx which eventually gives me the login window.  Unfortunately, when I tried to upgrade to 11.04 the update manager hanged for 20 minutes at (checking package manager) so I had to force reboot.  I'm updating through the server command line and it's starting to get messy.  I'm wondering if I could remove the server "part" or have to reinstall via the Live CD.

Comment: Just a note: forcing reboot while upgrading your system usually cases lots of trouble. It's likely your system will be no longer usable and you will have to reinstall it (you have been warned, though, before upgrade began). If you are lucky you will be able to fix what was broken, but this may be very difficult and may cause serious long-term issues.

Comment: I'm upgrading to 11.04 right now with no issues, still upgrading though

Comment: You were right...  There are errors ;O.  Apparently dpkg is going into recovery mode to fix them though.  I'll see what happens...

Comment: Its...  Pretty much toast.  Somehow xubuntu is installed and is messing things up, even though I removed it.  I wish there was a command to fix packages or fix the system....  Xorg doesn't work, xstart doesn't work...

Comment: That's usual in case of interrupted upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue; kinda.  Ubuntu was wayy too slow on my harddware, so I am currently installing a desktop version of PPC Lubuntu:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1798792

Comment: I doubt if that's an answer to this question! :)

Comment: I couldn't fix it pretty much.  As you mentioned, it totally messed up the installation.